Typescript importing interfaces in other files throwing error
I am new to typescript and am using it for a web app I am using with vue.js.
I am seeing that it is recommended that everything in typescript be assigned a type and in my web app I am passing some objects between files that have the same type.
I created some interfaces for these objects so that I can assign them a type and added them to the file /src/types/index.ts
export interface User {
    slug: string;
    name: string;
    email: string;
};

export interface Page {
    count: number;
    current_page: number;
    has_next: boolean;
    has_prev: boolean;
    page_size: number;
    total_pages: number;
};

When I go to import this in another file
import { Page } from '@/types';

I get the error:
SyntaxError: The requested module '/src/types/index.ts?t=1726778005111' does not provide an export named 'Page'
At first I thought this was an error with my file structure and how I was referencing the import.  However after trying many things to no avail, I tried exporting a const in the same file.
/src/types/index.ts
export const DATA = "DATA";

When I try to import the const it work!
import { DATA } from '@/types';
console.log(DATA);

No error and I am able to view the data.
What is happening here and am I missing something with how exporting interfaces should work?  I would prefer not having to add interfaces all throughout my code inside each module and copy-pasting the same code.
Also here is my tsconfig.js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "lib": ["DOM", "ESNext"],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    },
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "types": [
      "vite/client",
      "vite-plugin-vue-layouts/client",
      "unplugin-vue-router/client"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "strict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*",
    "src/**/*.vue",
  ],
  "exclude": ["dist", "node_modules", "cypress"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }],
}



Exporting and importing should work the same way for interfaces as they do for constants, can you reproduce it in an online env?

Simple solution:

Change the path from '@/types' to a relative path such as: '/src/types/index.ts'


I tried this and it doesnt work, I still get the error SyntaxError: The requested module '/src/types/index.ts' does not provide an export named 'Page' :(
